# Why Task.WhenAll(taskList) doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, task

If the task in `foreach` isn't `async`, and make `ping.Send` instead of
`ping.SendPingAsync` then `Task.WhenAll(taskList)` will work.

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();   

foreach (var host in hostArray)
{
    var aHost = host;
    Task task = new Task(async ()=>        
    {
        Ping ping = new Ping();
        PingResult pingRes = new PingResult { HostNameOrAddress = aHost };
        for (int i = 0; i < _pingCount; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                PingReply reply = await ping.SendPingAsync(aHost,1000);
                if (reply.Status == IPStatus.Success)
                    pingRes.RoundtripTimes.Add(reply.RoundtripTime);
            }
            catch
            {
                // ignored
            }
        }

        Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
        {
            _pingResultList.Add(pingRes);                                
        });
    });

    taskList.Add(task);
    task.Start();
}

await Task.WhenAll(taskList); //Never wait.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use Task's constructor. It doesn't support asynchronous lambda. Instead use `Task.Run`.

Your code at the moment waits only till your `SendPingAsync` is called in your tasks, not for the whole asynchronous method to finish. Because as soon as first await point hit, asynchronous methods return.

Your async lambda compiles to `Task(Action)` which means it gets compiled as async void method. Since there is no easy way to wait for async void methods, Task class constructor doesn't support it. Conversely `Task.Run` supports asynchronous method via [`Task.Run(Func<Task>)`  overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160382%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Since this returns a `Task`, Run method can easily wait for its completion.

Not only with asynchronous methods, always prefer `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`(if you need more control). There is almost no reason for one to use `Task` constructor.

If you decide to use `StartNew` for the asynchronous methods, you'll have to call [Task.UnWrap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd780917%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and wait for the task returned by it. When you're using Task.Run, you get this for free.

Answer (score 6):

When your anonymous method is asynchronous, you should use the `Task.Run` method instead of the `Task` constructor.

```
foreach (var host in hostArray)
{
    Task task = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        // ...
    });

    taskList.Add(task);
}

await Task.WhenAll(taskList);
```

The C# compiler converts asynchronous methods to a `Func<Task>` delegate. Consequently, when you run them through a task, the outer task would actually be a `Task<Task>` – namely, a task that generates another task when executed.

The `Task` constructor (like the `Task.Factory.StartNew` method) is impervious to the fact that your anonymous method *itself* returns a task that needs to be awaited upon; instead, it just waits on the outer task, which completes as soon as your anonymous method reaches its end.

`Task.Run`, on the other hand, has overloads that can handle such `Func<Task>` delegates by *unwrapping* them and waiting on their inner task. Thus, it will wait on the inner task representing the completion of the `SendPingAsync` call.